PyCharm Community Edition 2024.3 . Terminal console is not editable
I just started learning programming and for this I installed python and PyCharm Community Edition 2024.3 on my pc. But I can't edit text and code in the Terminal console of this program, because it is not editable. I can't figure out why this is so. And this massage appears every time  I try to open new windows in this Terminal console : "Process terminal Local is running. Do you want to terminate the process 'Terminal local?'".
screenshot from my pc
I press the cancel button but I still can't edit text and code in this Terminal console.
I reinstalled python and PyCharm Community Edition 2024.3, but it did not help. The problem still remains. The terminal console is not editable.
I also tried changing the Terminal console settings, but that didn't help either
PyCharm Community Edition 2024.3 settings for Terminal console
Could you please help me figure out why this is happening. How to fix this. And why I cant edit text and code in Terminal console? How to fix this so that I can edit in the Terminal console?

Thank you all. The problem is solved)
https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/14r6mdf/changing_terminal_shell/
"Help | Find Action," type registry, Enter
Disable terminal.use.conpty.on.windows
Restart PyCharm
